# Guide me to learn iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to coding, but i am interested in learning objective-C. From Where do i start learning objective-C for making iOS apps ?

I have started studying **"Programming in Objective-C"** by Stephen G Kochan. And I am going good and understanding well. it would be greatly appreciated if i am provided with some tutorials

thanks in advance

Comment: There are many resources available on the net for learning to write iOS apps.  The [Stanford iOS course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) is popular.  This site is for specific programming problems.

Comment: This isn't the site for this sort of thing. If you get stuck on code or how to do something, come back and ask. However, i will suggest a great book I learnt from: Big Nerd Ranch: Objective-C. Very good book and assumes no previous programming experience.

Comment: Thank You rob mayoff and Tander for your valuable replies. Will be coming off with programming questions in the future.

Comment: You must have to see the site [raywenderlich](www.raywenderlich.com) , which provide you good way to understand ios.

Comment: Gone through this website [www.raywenderlich.com ] . It seemed to be paid tutorials. (your wish) Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 guides about getting started with Objective-C, which helped me quite a lot when I started developing in Xcode. You should take a look at this:

http://cocoadevcentral.com/

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1

Comment: Thank you Elendas. http://cocoadevcentral.com/ looks easier to learn

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html)

Stanford [iOS course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550)

And google <3

Comment: @user3496717 No problem :) (And if you find this is the correct answer, you can mark it as correct so we'll both get reputation :p)